# ListView with GridView selected row - remove 3D appearance

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a WPF ListView that contains a GridView. I want the selected row to look "flat" and not 3d style.

Dose anyone know how to do this? 
Thanks, 
Smadar

Comment: Is it WPF or Windows 8 modern apps? GridView/ListView does not exist in WPF (but do exist in GridView)

Comment: What do you mean GridView/ListView doesn't exist in WPF?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx

Answer (score 9):

The 3D look is part of the default style.  To change this you need to replace the `ControlTemplate` for `ListViewItem`.  Here's a simple example which produces the following: [image: ListView screenshot]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="A"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.Items>
                <ListViewItem Content="Item 1"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Item 2"/>
                <ListViewItem Content="Item 3"/>
            </ListView.Items>

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding     BorderThickness}" 
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="1"   BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11" />
                                                <RowDefinition />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#75FFFFFF" />
                                            <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note: The default templates are located here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx.  Since there is no way to change part of a `ControlTemplate` or base one off of an existing template, I usually try to keep as much of the default template as I can, and only change the parts I care about.  It's a little verbose but should do what you're looking for.